# Display subset of data based on string pattern on template variable dropdown in table panel

Tags: grafana, grafana-templating

Grafana Version: 6.2.5

Elastic search

I have logs data with pattern ERR,INFO,DEBUG
Example “data_ERR_notconnected”, “sys_INFO_connected”, “sys_DEBUG_network”

I am trying to create template variable for ‘marker’ with variable dropdown as ERR,INFO,DEBUG. So when ERR is clicked from dropdown only error based data is displayed in table format panel.

[Drop down image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssTju.png)
[regex used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sErgl.png)
I am using regex as /.*(ERR|INFO|SH)/ but i dont see any change in response. Basically i am not able to group a values based on string pattern in a template variable? Is there anyway i could group the values based on string pattern? Any idea would be helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your regex with  `/.*_(ERR|INFO|SH)_.*/`
This should give you ERR,  INFO, SH as value of the dropdown